# Prevent react-router from trying to access non existing object (in redux)? (simple blog site)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm a bit stuck, I am trying to write a blog type of things which enables the user to navigate through the posts. I use react router for this, so that whenever the user navigates to `/posts/:id`, the relevant post will be shown.

So far I have this:

```
import React from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

import {fetchPost} from '../actions/posts.actions.js'


class PostView extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.setNextPost = this.setNextPost.bind(this);
    this.setPreviousPost = this.setPreviousPost.bind(this);
  }

  setPreviousPost() {
    var {id} = this.props.match.params;

    if(id>1) {
      id--;
    }
    this.props.history.push('/posts/'+id);
  }

  setNextPost() {
    var {id} = this.props.match.params;
    id++; //i need to have something (maybe here? or elsewhere in this file?) that does not let the id go too high
    this.props.history.push('/posts/'+id);
  }

  render() {
    // var {id} = this.props.match.params;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.activePost.post}</h1>
        {/* <h1>{this.props.posts[id].post}</h1> */}
        <button onClick={this.setPreviousPost}>Previous</button>
        <button onClick={this.setNextPost}>Next</button>
      </div>
      );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps ({posts}, ownProps) {
  return {
    activePost: posts[ownProps.match.params.id]
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPost})(PostView);
```

Say I have 10 posts in total. With the above code, if the user navigates to `posts/11`, I get an error (since the post simply does not exist, thus is undefined):

```
index_bundle.js:53908 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined
    at PostView.render (index_bundle.js:53908)
    at index_bundle.js:37770
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (index_bundle.js:37050)
```

So I need to somehow prevent the user from navigating to a post, which does not exist. I don't know how to do this.

**Some more background:** Initially, I created the code with a CurrentPost Reducer, which always holds the current post, until someone in some tutorial pointed out that this should rather not be saved in a separate reducer, since reactrouter already holds the `post id` in `posts/:id` which can then be used to fetch the post from my `posts reducer`. This sounded good to me, and I changed things around, however, now I don't know where and how to validate my data is correct, and I'm not sure if it's a good idea to do all of this in the component itself.

edit:

I have a posts reducer which holds all the posts. It is a big javascript object and looks like this:

```
{ 
"1" : {post: "post no 1", title: "Hello", ...}, 
"2" : {post: "post content no. 2", title: "...", }, 
//...
}.
```

I don't currently hold the number of posts in that reducer. I also do not (currently) pass the big posts reducer down to my single post view component (the one i cite above), and just get the post at the relevant id for now.

Comment: Do you have access to the list of IDs for posts in this component? I.E is it or could it be passed as prop?

Comment: Hm. I have a `posts reducer` which holds all the posts. It is a big javascript object and looks like this: `{ "1" : {//... first post object}, "2" : {// second post object}, //...}`. So I don't currently hold the number of posts in that reducer. I also do not (currently) pass the big posts reducer down to my single post view component (the one i cite above), and just get the post at the relevant id for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your state model add a value for total posts. Then map it to the props. Can't post any code for this without seeing what you already have.

You can then put a ternary in the render method to only show prev or next buttons when there is something to go to.

```
render() {
    var {id} = this.props.match.params;
    var { totalPosts } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.activePost.post}</h1>
        {/* <h1>{this.props.posts[id].post}</h1> */}
        {id <= 1 ? null : <button onClick={this.setPreviousPost}>Previous</button>}
        {id === totalPosts ? null: <button onClick={this.setNextPost}>Next</button>}
      </div>
    );
}
```

EDIT: Add an extra prop via `mapStateToProps` like so.

```
function mapStateToProps ({posts}, ownProps) {
  return {
    activePost: posts[ownProps.match.params.id],
    totalPosts: Object.keys(posts).length
  };
}
```

Comment: my problem is where to put this `totalPosts` variable, since I am using Redux and aim to prevent my single post component to deal with the reducer which holds all posts.

Comment: You are already using `posts` in `mapStateToProps` so you can just create a new value. Something like `totalPosts: posts.length`

Comment: perfect, thank you! that worked perfectly! Sorry I only understood what you meant after the edit! Thanks a lot!